# How to ergonomically iterate over functions with different signatures

Tags: python, function, design-patterns, functor, signature

I have a "genotype" of sorts which contains genes.  What those genes represent is not important, they are just arbitrary objects which can all be referenced as "gene objects".

I need to mutate this gene, via several methods, however not all of the function signatures match up.  Given a starting gene a new gene is created with a random chance to select one of these methods (or no method) for mutation.

For example, I have `duplicate(gene)`, `replace(gene, othergene)`, `insert(gene, othergene)`, `delete(gene)`, and `othermutation(gene, genotype)`.   All of these return a list of genes (even if the list only contains one element, or zero elements) in order to maintain homogeneity among the function signatures.

I want to generalize the situation to a list of these mutation functions and associated percentage chance to be used.   I already have methods of selecting these genes via binary search and cumulative distributions, I generate an R and can retrieve the correct function based on the rounded binary index from R.  This roughly allows me to do the following:

```
def mutate(genotype, mutation_list, cumulative_probabilities)
    mutated_genotype = []
    for gene in genotype:
        r = random.random()
        mutation = mutation_list(cumulative_probabilities(r))
        mutated_genotype.extend(mutation(gene))
    return mutated_genotype
```

Ideally I don't need to know the mutation on the fifth line, I just need to have a mutation list somewhere with associated probabilities.  As you can see, what happens with `replace(gene, othergene)` which requires a second parameter?  Or `othermutation(gene, genotype)` which requires a different but also separate parameter?

In order to solve this problem I've come to several solutions.  First, I could assimilate all function signatures to be exactly the same.  What I mean by this is that even though `duplicate(gene)` doesn't need `othergene` I would still put that in the function definition, it just wouldn't use it or it would do something trivial with it.  But the downside with this solution is that every time I need to add a new function with new parameters, I'll need to change all function signatures, which violates SRP in a class sort of way for all functions and would be annoying to deal with.  But I could wrap it as one parameter object where I set needed parameters on each iteration.  In the event that a new function with new types of arguments were needed, I could simply add that argument to the "mutation parameter" object, and pass this object to every function, and every function would only get what it needs, for example:

```
for gene in genotype:
    #note other gene is created from some other function or is a generator itself
    mutation_parameter = MutationParameter(gene, genotype, othergene)
    r = random.random()
    mutation = mutation_list(cumulative_probabilities(r))
    mutated_genotype.extend(mutation(mutation_parameter))
```

The stickler here is that the members of `MutationParameter` aren't necessarily all that related to one another and we have to know about what the mutation signatures are before hand, you won't just be able to add a new signature, multiple sections of code will need to be updated.

Another way I could deal with this is I could make the function parameters generic, but in this way I would be forced to add an extra datastructure that handles the pulling of data into the function signature (so that all functions take `*args` or `**kwargs`) and this would possibly mean tailored functions for each signature and decreased performance due to the need to linearize or associate cumulative probabilities with a hashtable/dictionary.

I could handle the functions by making functors which store some of the data for the parameters in the calling 'function' itself (such as the "other gene" as say a generator that randomly produces a gene).  This would require me to create a new class for each function in order to handle this situation for each function that required unique parameters. Even then, I couldn't put, say, the current list of genes, the `genotype` into `othermutation` with out creating the list of functions at call during the execution of the function itself (so not all functors couldn't be passed in as the `mutation_list` in `mutate`.

Still I might just have to bit the bullet and separate some mutation types that require certain types of information from others if I want to have a nice way of dealing with a generic `mutation_list` and I could just pass in two types of mutation lists.

I could additionally do a similar thing by making, say, the othergene parameter a static function/variable to the functor that all of the instantiations would have.

So to summarize three methods:

1. pass all parameters in via parameter object, functions pick and choose which parameters they need;
2. use *args to do effectively the same thing, but you also need an associated function for each signature to pull out data;
3. or use functors (either with or with out static variables) to hold the data with another separate passed in mutation list for mutation functions where extra parameters can't be determined before `mutation` is called.

I want to avoid having my mutate function care about what the underlying mutations are, such that it can be generic as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because I've found the current answers unsatisfactory (and nearly exactly the same as my suggested answer), but have found this solution to be the most "ergonomic" for my specific situation (the most generic etc, well formed and extensible).

My first suggestion,

> 1: pass all parameters in via parameter object, functions pick and
>   choose which parameters they need

I found to be the best for me, possibly even outside Python and into non dynamic languages.   What this basically looks like is this:

```
class MutationParameters:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3 ...):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3
        ...

def mutate(genes, mutator_generator, otherparams...):
    # paraminit...
    new_genes = []
    mutation_params = MutationParameters(param1, param2, param3...)
    for gene in genes:
        # runtime param init ...
        mutation_params.paramn = paramn #runtime param
        new_genes = next(mutator_generator)(mutation_params)
        new_genes.extend(new_genes)
    return StackGenotype(new_genes)
```

If a new param is needed?  Update MutationParameters, update mutate once, that's it, no need to change the parameters of all the other functions (hence why using parameters and ignoring some is not a good idea, similar for functor).  Add a new function?  Just need one variable, and look for the param you need inside of it.  This would also work in c++.

It is my belief, unless some one posts a better answer, that this is the best solution to my problem, and I will mark this as the answer until a better answer appears.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable strategy is to wrap the functions of one argument with another function that supplies but doesn't use the other argument:

```
def dup2(gene, othergene):
    return duplicate(gene)

def del2(gene, othergene):
    return delete(gene)
```

The will make the two shorter signatures match the other functions: `replace(gene, othergene), insert(gene, othergene), othermutation(gene, genotype)`.

Another strategy is to use `try/except` to test the possibilities:

```
try:
    return func(gene, othergene)     # try two-arguments
except TypeError:
    return func(gene)                # try one-argument
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is: how do you know what parameters to provide for each function call, since they don't have the same signature?  I think there is a good way to avoid providing arguments that you don't need, and structuring the program in an understandable way: use classes instead of simple functions.  Classes provide a way to check how many and what type of arguments are required by the working functions.  You can factor this code into a base class.  For example:

```
class MutatorBase:
   def __init__(self, needs_othergene=False, needs_genotype=False):
        self.needs_othergene = needs_othergene
        self.needs_genotype = needs_genotype

   def f(self, gene, othergene=None, genotype=None):
        """This is the function that does the actual calculations"""
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now you make a bunch of derived classes where you implement the actual functions `f`.  In the constructors you set the variables `needs_othergene` and `needs_genotype`.  Example:

```
class Duplicator(MutatorBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def f(self, gene):
        return duplicate(gene)

class Replacer(MutatorBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(needs_othergene=True)

    def f(self, gene, othergene=g):
        return replace(gene, g)
```

Before you call one of these, say it's named `replacer.f`, you check the variables to see what kind of arguments are required.  You set up the function call appropriately.  Instead of associating probabilities with a set of functions, you associate probabilities with a set of classes.  In Python they're equally easy.